# Where to find Google cloud platform id?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wanted to create an account to new [google vision api](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) to possibly integrate its service in the app http://www.openbricks.io I am working on.

But the [form](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/visionapialpha/) to have access to this new api ask for an account on Google Cloud platform, it is my case, but also a mystical Google Cloud platform user account Id, I cannot find no where Google Cloud help is a real maze and to have support we need to pay.

Is anyone using Google Cloud Platform? And know how to get this id ?

Answer (score 10):

It is simply the email address you're using for Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and worked for me. I had followed the help-text instructions to look at my billing statement, but none of those IDs were accepted.

Answer (score -4):

To use the Google Cloud Platform, you create a [project](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview/#projects), which handles billing, team access, API configuration and the like - all api calls and such will be associated with a project. Those projects have an id, which I think is what you're referring to.

In brief: you create a project by creating it in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com). Once you've created a project, there should be a field in the UI that specifies the project id.

Comment: OP was asking about the Google Cloud Platform user account ID, not the project ID. It says to look at your billing statement, but none of those IDs are accepted by the form field.